# access TextBoxes inside DataTemplate

Tags: wpf, data-binding

I know question similar to this has asked several times in SO. But non of them address my issue and have some difficulty with understanding those answers. This is my situation; I have a `ItemsControl` I have used `ItemTemplate` and bound some data.

```
<Window.Resources>        
    <DataTemplate x:Key="AdditionalFieldTemlate">
        <Grid>
            <TextBlock Text="{Binding InfoName}"/>
            <TextBox Text="{Binding InfoValue,Mode=TwoWay}" Name="CustomValue"/>
        </Grid>
    </DataTemplate>
</Window.Resources>
<Grid>
    <ItemsControl ItemsSource="{Binding AdditionalInformation}" x:Name="additionalInfo" ItemTemplate="{DynamicResource AdditionalFieldTemlate}"/>
</Grid>
```

I need to set `TextBox` text to empty(all the textboxes text inside datatemplate) once click on a `Button`. Don't know how to access these textboxes. Please help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't normally access the TextBoxes (the look) ....you access the data that is being bound to.

So you can just alter the "data" in your collection as follows:

```
foreach (var item in AdditionalInformation)
{
    item.InfoValue = "";
}
```

The "TextBoxes" will then be emptied.

Make sure you have implemented `INotifyPropertyChanged` on the class being used by `AdditionalInformation`....so that when the `InfoValue` property is altered it raises a notification.

Answer (score 0):

The text in the textboxes is databound to the InfoValue property of your class. Implement the class and proprty like this:

```
class InfoClass: INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private string _infoValue;

    ...

    public string InfoValue
    {
        get { return _infoValue; }
        set
        {
            _infoValue = value;
            OnNotifyPropertyChanged("InfoValue")
        }
    }

    ...

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void OnPropertyChanged(string property)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(property));
    }
}
```

Then do what colinsmith suggests in your button click handler (or command if you went with the MVVM approach). The binding will be notified to the change and the view will be updated.